# Adding flex-active class to the li instead of a/img

Tags: jquery, flexslider

When we enable `controlNav`, we get nice paging list and some usefull class like `flex-active`. but the class added to the link or image(when thumbnail control enabled). like this:

```
<ol class="flex-control-nav">
    <li><a class="flex-active">1</a></li>
    <li><a>1</a></li>
</ol>
```

How to move flex-active class to the li element instead of a/img element to get something like this:

```
<ol class="flex-control-nav">
    <li class="flex-active"><a>1</a></li>
    <li><a>1</a></li>
</ol>
```

**edit**: here the script i used to show flexslider with thumbnail control:

```
$('.clients-items').flexslider({
    animation: 'slide',
    controlNav: 'thumbnails',
    directionNav: false,
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please provide the jQuery you are using to get more precise answer but could you use something like this?

```
$('.clients-items').flexslider({
    animation: 'slide',
    controlNav: 'thumbnails',
    directionNav: false,
    start: function(){
        $('.flex-control-nav .flex-active').parent('li').addClass('flex-active').siblings().removeClass('flex‌​-active');
    },
    after: function(){
        $('.flex-control-nav .flex-active').parent('li').addClass('flex-active').siblings().removeClass('flex‌​-active');
    }
});
```

Comment: Is my updated answer any help? Please tell me what is wrong so I can understand it better and fix it :)

Comment: FYI, the slide changes automatically, and the flex-active class also move to another active slide. so i think its also related to the changing slide event

Comment: that won't work i think :) please experiment with the slider too.

Comment: Can you put your code in jsfiddle? I lack the imagination to get the problem precise enough it seems

Comment: Are we getting any closer now? :)

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, i Edited your script to look like this, and it's work. 

`start:function(){
       $('.flex-control-nav .flex-active').parent('li').addClass('flex-active').siblings().removeClass('flex-active');
      },
      after: function(){
       $('.flex-control-nav .flex-active').parent('li').addClass('flex-active').siblings().removeClass('flex-active');

can you change your script too so i can accept your answer :)
}`

Comment: Good! :) I updated my answer for documentation purposes so someone else can see the correct ansdwe in future is she/he faces the same problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58737/discussion-between-ariona-rian-and-defain).

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way would be using

```
.parent('li');
```

So something like

```
jQuery('.flex-control-nav').find('a.flex-active')
    .removeClass('flex-active')   // remove the class from the a
    .parent('li')                 // select the parent of the a,.. li that is.
    .addClass('flex-active');     // add the flex-active class to the parent li.
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution and its work for me

```
start: function() {
         //-- Add flexslider active class to li of nav control instead of just on the image
         if ($('.testimonial-section .flexslider ol.flex-control-nav').length > 0) {
             // initial check and addition
             $('.testimonial-section .flexslider ol.flex-control-nav li').each(function() {
                 if ($(this).children('img').hasClass('flex-active')) {
                     $(this).children('img').removeClass('flex-active');
                     $(this).addClass('flex-active');
                 } else {
                     $(this).removeClass('flex-active');
                 }
             });
             // bind into flexslider callback and run dynamically
             $('.testimonial-section .flexslider').bind('start', function(event, slider) {
                 $('.testimonial-section .flexslider ol.flex-control-nav li').each(function() {
                     if ($(this).children('img').hasClass('flex-active')) {
                         $(this).children('img').removeClass('flex-active');
                         $(this).addClass('flex-active');
                     } else {
                         $(this).removeClass('flex-active');
                     }
                 });
             });
         }
     },
     after: function() {
         //-- Add flexslider active class to li of nav control instead of just on the image
         if ($('.testimonial-section .flexslider ol.flex-control-nav').length > 0) {
             // initial check and addition
             $('.testimonial-section .flexslider ol.flex-control-nav li').each(function() {
                 if ($(this).children('img').hasClass('flex-active')) {
                     $(this).children('img').removeClass('flex-active');
                     $(this).addClass('flex-active');
                 } else {
                     $(this).removeClass('flex-active');
                 }
             });
             // bind into flexslider callback and run dynamically
             $('.testimonial-section .flexslider').bind('after', function(event, slider) {
                 $('.testimonial-section .flexslider ol.flex-control-nav li').each(function() {
                     if ($(this).children('img').hasClass('flex-active')) {
                         $(this).children('img').removeClass('flex-active');
                         $(this).addClass('flex-active');
                     } else {
                         $(this).removeClass('flex-active');
                     }
                 });
             });
         }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
start: function(){
    $('.flex-control-nav .flex-active').parent('li').addClass('flex-active').siblings().removeClass('flex‌​-active');
},
after: function(){
    $('.flex-control-nav li').removeClass('flex-active');
    $('.flex-control-nav .flex-active').parent('li').addClass('flex-active').siblings().removeClass('flex‌​-active');
}
```